# Print command line output into a text file in Linux (Ubuntu)

Tags: c++, linux, command-line

I have a C++ program in Linux (Ubuntu) which prints very long output in a command terminal.

How can i copy this output from command terminal directly to the .txt file by Linux command?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your shell does this for you by virtue of output redirection:

```
$ ./a.out > theoutput.txt
```

Comment: There is an error when i execute this command: bash: ./a.out: No such file or directory

Comment: @BlueBit: substitute the actual filename of own program... (or just call all your programs a.out, as you were meant to :-))

Answer (score 2):

In general you type;

```
command > file.txt
```

The greater than symbol > redirects standard out to the file.

Comment: Exactly. You "pipe" the output to a file.

Comment: Well actually pipe would be used to send stdout to stdin of another process i.e. "command | command2". Not the same thing.

Comment: An improvement would be to keep `stdout` and `stderr` separately: `command 1>outFile 2>errFile`.